# Условие не видит Ajax результат

Tags: php, jquery

Отправляю определенный пост запрос на сервер и исходя из отправленных данных получаю ответ от сервера Success либо Updated.

Примерно так обрабатывает сервер:

```php
    if($data>0) {
      //Мой код
      return 'Success';
    } else {
      //Мой код
      return 'Updated';
    }
```

Таким образом отправляю ajax запрос на фронте:

```js
    $.ajax({
        url : action,
        method : "POST",
        data : {id:id, user: user},
        dataType : "text",
        success : function (data) {
            if(data == 'Success') {
                alert(data);
            } else if(data == 'Updated') {
                alert(data);
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

else if используется для того, что сервер может возвращать и другие данные кроме Success и Updated.

Собственно вопрос - В чем ошибка? почему при ответе от сервера ничего не происходит, но данные успешно отправляются. И на сервере никаких ошибок.

Comment: посмотрите что приходит в запросе через консоль например

Comment: по приведенному примеру кода пхп вообще не понятно что вы с этим делаете. Куда возвращает этот `return` ? Где у вас происходит условно `echo json_encode()` данных, или хотя бы просто `echo $result` ?

Comment: Может в php команда json_encode и не понадобится, раз вы тип данных в аяксе указали как text, но вместо return нужно использовать echo.

Comment: @Quazimorda, да, ошибка была именно в этом. Заменил return на echo. Благодарю.